# What is a html snapshot ( for google crawler )

Tags: html, web-crawler, snapshot

I've been searching for an example of a "HTML Snapshot" , for google bot crawler, but still i don't have a clue what the "snap shot" is like ? From the way i understand, i figure it's my page's html put together into a large string ?

Thanks alot !

Comment: Since this isn't about coding, you're most likely best-served by posting on http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right, that's exactly what it is. A HTML snapshot is the static HTML code that you want Google to find when crawling your Website. 10 years ago, it was pretty much the same thing as the HTML source code. Today, especially in SPA (single page applications), the HTML changes without reloading the page. That means that there is not always a proper URL associated to every HTML possible. The snapshot is that kind of generated HTML that you want to present to Google.

That's why you can find products such as https://ajaxsnapshots.com/
It's a Javascript code that take "pictures" of your HTML pages as they are generated to make sure that the code fetched by Google bot is meaningful.